# Flex Hero: Can i access Android compass?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, compass-geolocation

Is it possible to use Air on android and access the compass? I saw there is some acceleration support (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/Accelerometer.html) but what about the compass?

If it is NOT accessible, would it be possible to do some communication between a native android-app listening for compass update and an air application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANEs to create a bridge between AIR and native functionality. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9VMPM5RfQI

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  It doesn't seem to be included in the `flash.sensors` package just yet.  I'm hoping that will change soon enough.  I don't think it's possible to have Air on Android communicate with a 3rd party app within the mobile environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, then i won't use flex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use heading of the Geolocation as an alternative way.